# Select columns and apply border based on today's date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data with various columns. The top row contains a range of dates and I need the column with today's date to be highlighted with a thick border and then for this to highlight the relevant column for any day the sheet is used?

Date format is: 28/02/2014

Thanks for you help

Comment: have you done anything so far?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [CONDITIONAL FORMATTING](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx):

**1)** Select range with your data (i.e. `A1:L13`)

[image]

**2)** *With selected range* go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule.."*

[image]

**3)** Select *"Use formula..."* rule type, enter formula `=A$1=TODAY()` where `A1` is a *top left cell* of your range. Choose desired format and press *"OK"*

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct:) See this link for details: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235